# Unable to get product Id in windows 2008 server

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008

i want to use ProductId of windows machine so i have written this code 
but this code is unable to get the ProductId from the registry when running on windows server 2008 
when i have visited registry the ProductId is there in Registry

```
string[] names = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValueNames();
foreach (string s in names)
{
  listBox1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean its "unable" to get the ProductID?  When this code is run, what is contained in the string array **names**

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason this happens. It's because your program is 32-bit and your system is 64-bit. 32-bit programs access the 32-bit portion of the registry, and this key is not present in the 32-bit portion, which is located in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Compile your program in 64-bit and it's will work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account this code is running under has permissions to read from the registry (or at least that location in the registry).

Comment: i am Able to Get all the Information in that section of registry except ProductId ,i have administrator rights what can be the reason for this

Comment: @NitinBourai - When debugging does `names` contain it?

Comment: when i am running the code in OS other than windows 2008 the names contain the ProductId but when i am running on 2008 names does not contain ProductId is this some kind of security in 2008 ?

Comment: @NitinBourai - I am not aware of such a feature. Does the key exist in the registry on that computer?

Comment: @NitinBourai - Then I can only assume there are permission issues.